# How do I group the results by company?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have the following [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/31821/9):

```
CREATE TABLE companies (pk serial PRIMARY KEY, name text, max int);

INSERT INTO companies(name, max) 
VALUES
  ('Company A', 3),
  ('Company B', 8),
  ('Company C', -1);

CREATE TABLE employees (pk serial PRIMARY KEY, company integer REFERENCES companies (pk), 
                    name text, joined timestamp);

INSERT INTO employees (company, name, joined)
VALUES 
  (2, 'Jane',    '2015-09-23 14:46:57'),
  (2, 'Jack',    '2015-09-23 14:46:57'),
  (3, 'Frank',   '2015-09-23 14:51:07'),
  (2, 'Bob',     '2015-09-23 14:56:11'),
  (1, 'Carl',    '2015-09-23 16:12:05'),
  (1, 'Jason',   '2015-09-23 16:15:35'),
  (3, 'Fred',    '2015-09-23 16:28:35'),
  (2, 'Bruce',   '2015-09-23 16:35:51'),
  (1, 'Brian',   '2015-09-23 16:36:17'),
  (1, 'Ryan',    '2015-09-23 16:36:22'),
  (1, 'Peter',   '2015-09-23 16:37:04'),
  (3, 'Ed',      '2015-09-23 16:37:11'),
  (2, 'Jenny',   '2015-09-23 16:37:15'),
  (2, 'Jessica', '2015-09-24 09:52:46'),
  (3, 'Anita',   '2015-09-24 10:01:19'),
  (3, 'Melanie', '2015-09-24 10:05:27'),
  (3, 'Kathryn', '2015-09-24 10:05:29'),
  (2, 'Ashely',  '2015-09-24 10:19:46'),
  (1, 'Valerie', '2015-09-24 14:49:05'),
  (2, 'Jimmy',   '2015-09-24 15:42:45'),
  (3, 'Johnny',  '2015-09-24 17:38:06'),
  (1, 'Mick',    '2015-09-25 14:49:10');

SELECT *  -- choose the columns you want here
FROM (SELECT e.*, c.max,
             row_number() over (partition by company order by joined desc) as rank
      FROM employees e JOIN
           companies c
           on e.company = c.pk
     ) e
WHERE rank <= max or max = -1
```

This gives:

```
pk  company name    joined  max rank
22  1   Mick    2015-09-25T14:49:10Z    3   1
19  1   Valerie 2015-09-24T14:49:05Z    3   2
11  1   Peter   2015-09-23T16:37:04Z    3   3
20  2   Jimmy   2015-09-24T15:42:45Z    8   1
18  2   Ashely  2015-09-24T10:19:46Z    8   2
14  2   Jessica 2015-09-24T09:52:46Z    8   3
13  2   Jenny   2015-09-23T16:37:15Z    8   4
8   2   Bruce   2015-09-23T16:35:51Z    8   5
4   2   Bob 2015-09-23T14:56:11Z    8   6
1   2   Jane    2015-09-23T14:46:57Z    8   7
2   2   Jack    2015-09-23T14:46:57Z    8   8
21  3   Johnny  2015-09-24T17:38:06Z    -1  1
17  3   Kathryn 2015-09-24T10:05:29Z    -1  2
16  3   Melanie 2015-09-24T10:05:27Z    -1  3
15  3   Anita   2015-09-24T10:01:19Z    -1  4
12  3   Ed  2015-09-23T16:37:11Z    -1  5
7   3   Fred    2015-09-23T16:28:35Z    -1  6
3   3   Frank   2015-09-23T14:51:07Z    -1  7
```

How do I get it so that the results are grouped by company? e.g. I'd like 3 rows (1 for each company) and then an array of the employees for each. For instance, Company A would look like:

```
1 [{"name": "Mick", "joined": "2015-09-25T14:49:10Z", "rank": 1},{"name": "Valerie", "joined": "2015-09-24T14:49:05Z", "rank": 2},{"name": "Peter", "joined": "2015-09-23T16:37:04Z", "rank": 3}]
```

I have been trying various GROUP By statements and keep running into varous errors where the sql is invalid, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample output looks a bit like a JSON array (however, not a valid JSON value), so maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
select c.pk, jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(e))
from employees e
  join companies c on e.company = c.pk
group by c.pk;
```

To get the three "most recent" employees you can use:

```
select c.pk, jsonb_agg(e3.emp)
from ( 
  select company, 
         to_jsonb(e) as emp, 
         row_number() over (partition by company order by joined desc) as rn
  from employees e
) e3
  join companies c on e.company = c.pk 
where e3.rn <= 3;
```

Online Example: https://rextester.com/RPSI96409

Comment: Yes, it s/b a json array of objects. However, you are changing the sql so that it is returning all the rows for all the companies when it should be returning only the most recent. For company A, I would like only 3 of the most recent records. B should have 8 and C is unlimited. I already have that sql statement for that part done. Question is how do I modify the statement I have?

Comment: @Nothingbetter: you never mentioned anything about "most recent" but that can easily be done.